# Selenium Webdriver - Select Drop down, input text and click

Tags: python, selenium

I got error: AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by'

```
url = "https://calculator.shipany.io/"
chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
sleep(5)
```

1.) How to use selenium to select drop down:

- Select "Hong Kong" in Origin

```
origin = driver.find_element_by(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='i_form']/div/div[2]/div[1]/select/option[2]")
origin.click()
```

- Select "Hong Kong" in Destination

```
destination = driver.find_element_by(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='i_form']/div/div[2]/div[2]/select/option[2]")
destination.click()
```

2.) How to input text in the placeholder of

- weight

```
weight = driver.find_element_by(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='i_form']/div/div[2]/div[3]/input[1]")
weight.send_keys("1")
```

- L(cm)

```
length = driver.find_element_by(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='L(cm)']")
length.send_keys("1")
```

- W(cm)

```
width = driver.find_element_by(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='dimension']/input[3]")
width.send_keys("1")
```

- H(cm)

```
height = driver.find_element_by(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='dimension']/input[6]")
height.send_keys("1")
```

3.) How to click the button for submit-form?

```
button = driver.find_element_by(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='i_form']/div/div[2]/div[5]/button[1]")
button.click()
```

Comment: What code have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: I tried driver.find_element_by(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='i_form']/div/div[2]/div[1]/select/option[2]").click()

Comment: And? What exception do you see? Also, what is the rest of your code?

Comment: I want select the drop down and input some text into the field and press the submit button. But i got error from it AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `find_element_by` you should use `find_element` method.
Like

```py
origin = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='i_form']/div/div[2]/div[1]/select/option[2]")
origin.click()
```

etc.
You can reduce the code above to be

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='i_form']/div/div[2]/div[1]/select/option[2]").click()
```

Also, you should use Expected Conditions explicit waits instead of hardcoded pauses like

```py
sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

The dropdown is `Select` component you can use Select class to access the element.

To handle dynamic element use `explicit` **wait** and wait for element to be visible.

```
driver.get("https://calculator.shipany.io/")
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
dropdownOrigin =wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='booking-form']//select[.//option[contains(.,'Origin')]]")))
selectOrigin=Select(dropdownOrigin)
selectOrigin.select_by_visible_text("Hong Kong")

dropdownDestination =wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='booking-form']//select[.//option[contains(.,'Destination')]]")))
selectDest=Select(dropdownDestination)
selectDest.select_by_visible_text("Hong Kong")
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
```

**Browser snapshot:**
[image]